# Nginx: choose alias depending on a query string parameter

Tags: nginx, location, nginx-config

I want my Nginx server to give away files depending on a query string parameter. I have directories for debug files and release files and want to distribute them according to a parameter value:

```
location /files/ {
    if ( $arg_isDebug = "true" )
    {
        alias "C:/DebugFiles/";
    }
    if ( $!arg_isDebug != "true" )
    {
        alias "C:/ReleaseFiles/Release/";
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error

> "alias" directive is not allowed here ...

Why can't I write it inside an 'if' statement and is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I write it inside an 'if' statement

[The documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) states that `alias` can **only** be used in a location context.

> is there a workaround for this?

Use a [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

For example:

```
map $arg_isDebug $alias {
default   "C:/ReleaseFiles/Release/";
true      "C:/DebugFiles/";
}

server {
    ...
    location ^~ /files/ {
        alias $alias;
    }
}
```

The `map` block is declared outside of the `server` block. Both the location value and alias value should end with `/` or neither end with `/`. You may want to use the [`^~` operator](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to avoid a potential conflict with any regular expression locations within the same server block.